# Trouble with setwd() in R

Tags: r, csv, setwd

My apologies if this has been answered already, I've looked through many very similar threads but haven't found a solution. I'm new to R, just started a few days ago but I feel like I'm making decent progress. I'm attempting to load in some old data from my undergrad thesis to mess around with a bit, but can't seem to get my working directory to change.

So far, I've created a path:

```
path<- file.path("C:", "Users", "Daniel", "Desktop",
                 "R_Practice", "Thesisdata.csv")
```

and I had success with reading the file designated by the path with

```
read.csv(path, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

However, when I try to use

```
setwd(path)
```

or

```
setwd("C:", "Users", "Daniel", "Desktop",
      "R_Practice", "Thesisdata.csv")
```

I get an error message reading

> Error in setwd(x) : cannot change working directory."

Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction? I don't really understand why it would be able to successfully read the file using the path but can't set it to the working directory.

Comment: you just need all of those as a single character string : `setwd("C/Users/Daniel....)`

Comment: That's a path to a file. You can't change directories to a file.

Comment: Thanks everybody! got it working

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're confusing a *directory* (`".../R_Practice"`) with a *file* (`".../R_Practice/thesisdata.csv"`). As @cory says in comments, you can't change the working directory to a file.

Try

```
path <- file.path("C:", "Users", "Daniel", "Desktop", "R_Practice")
setwd(path)
r <- read.csv("Thesisdata.csv")
```

Which should be equivalent to

```
r <- read.csv(file.path(path,"Thesisdata.csv"))
```

(except of course that the former approach leaves you in the appropriate working directory, so that you don't have to keep prepending the full path to your file names)

Furthermore, `setwd()` takes a single string: `setwd("C:",...,"R_Practice")` would never work in any case.

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.